# Why is Plotly creating multiple figures when I am using a for loop to add two traces each to two separate subplots?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to produce an output of two subplots each with two traces. I am using a for loop to each this and each time I am getting extra figures... the first figure contains one plot with the two traces, clearly from the first run through the for loop. There is space for the second subplot but it is entirely blank. Then below that is a second figure which correctly contains both subplots with traces as intended. I don't understand why extra figures are being created.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)
for i in np.arange(2): 
     (fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]),
                    row=i+1, col=1)
     .add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]),
                    row=i+1, col=1))
fig.show()
```

When I run the above it creates three separate figures: [fig 1][1], [fig 2][2], [fig 3][3]

What is going on here?  How to get the expected output of one figure with two subplots? Thanks.

New information:  When I run the above code in a new notebook I get the correct output of a single figure with two subplots.  However, when I run this code in my working notebook file I get the behavior described above.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly formatted question. This is only my second posted question and I struggled to get the formatting to be accepted by the parser!  Ideally the images would be posted inline.

Comment: The problem is in `fig.show()`. Looks like that is inside the FOR loop, so has one subplot plus a blank subplot for the first loop and both for the second time it loops. Remove indentation and try

Comment: Your code is graphing correctly. I have checked it with the latest version of plotly (5.10.0).

Comment: @r-beginners Yes I believe the same thing.  New information I will add to the issue.  When I run this code separately in a new notebook it works as expected, but when I run this code in my working notebook it has the behaviour I describe of displaying multiple figures.

Comment: @Redox I tried to add new information to the post and make the same edits you made and now I've saved without the links :|  I never would have guessed that posting to stack overflow was so finicky

Comment: Then it may not be a problem with plotly, but with the notebook. please do a kernel restart in the notebook and check the result.

Comment: @r-beginners Have tried that several times. I just restarted again though and same output.

Comment: @Redox Re: your comment that the fig.show() if in the FOR loop, I don't see how that is the case... what specific change would you suggest? The behavior would suggest you are right but as is outlined, the code works in a new notebook but not in my working notebook?!  It is very odd.